# How to find if a frequent word is concentrated in a specific part of text or evenly distributed?

Tags: python, nlp

I need to find out if, for example, the word **stackoverflow** is concentrated in a specific part of a text/string or more or less evenly distributed through out the text/string?

concentratedString = 'one **stackoverflow** two **stackoverflow** three four five **stackoverflow** six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen **stackoverflow** twenety twentyone twentytwo tentythree twentyfour twentyfive ...'

evenlydisString = 'one two three four five six **stackoverflow** seven eight nine ten eleven twelve **stackoverflow** thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen **stackoverflow** seventeen eighteen nineteen  twenety twentyone twentytwo tentythree twentyfour twentyfive **stackoverflow**...'

As can be noted, *concentratedString* has the word in question mostly in the first quadrant. Where as *evenlydisString* has the the word evenly distributed.

Is there a tool, preferable in python, that has this solution. If not, how would you go about this? 1) Loop trough the string, 2)Note postions, 3)Calculate distance between positions!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you'd want to start by getting the positions of the matching word in the text, and then apply a function to the list of those positions whose value will depend on how similar or dispersed they are.  Maybe use `stdev` as a starting point?

```
>>> from statistics import stdev
>>> def word_concentration(word: str, text: str) -> float:
...     return stdev(i for i, w in enumerate(text.split()) if w == word)
...
>>> word_concentration("stackoverflow", concentratedString)
9.5
>>> word_concentration("stackoverflow", evenlydisString)
6.027713773341708
```

Comment: I am getting different results: 9.5 for concentratedString and 9.251 for evenlydisString.